# Jenkins plugins can block projects to build if their upstream projects are failed to build?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

Anyone knows whether this kind of plugins are available? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by upstream project ?

Comment: @barun Hi, a project can have both downstream projects and upstream projects in jenkins

Comment: If Upstream project fails, the downstream projects aren't even attempted

Answer (score 0):

Please see the page [BuildResultTrigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BuildResultTrigger+Plugin)

> When you you have two jobs jobA and jobB and you want Jenkins to
>   schedule jobB after the jobA execution (whatever the build result of
>   jobA), you can configure Jenkins to say that jobB is the downstream
>   job of jobA. The drawback with this approach is that jobA has the
>   knowledge of its dependencies. With the BuildResultPlugin, you
>   configure jobB to monitor jobA build result. A build is scheduled if
>   there is a new build result matches your criteria (unstable, failure,
>   ...)

I think you have to configure different job for parent - child project in this approach

you can check also [Join Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin)